# parser error message '.master' is not a valid language extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

what is happen that i put change the root of the main master page and then i relocated as before but now i am facing this problem, i have read many of question of people they face the same case but i couldn't find a good solution or answer to fix this error, by the way i tried to change the root from "~/" to "../" and also add in the root the main project folder but its the same like: "../berava/" and the same case.

here is the code of master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/MasterPage.master" Inherits="MasterPage.master" %>
```

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to specify the master file with `CodeFile`. That should be a `cs` file.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply , but it same nothing work same error msg :-(